# jboss-as-maven-plugin: which directory does command "jboss-as:deploy" deploy an .ear to?

Tags: maven, maven-3, jboss7.x, war, ear

I am running jboss 7.1, maven 3, and a java ee6 application that generates an .ear
I am doing a `mvn clean package jboss:as-deploy`and Jboss-as-maven-plugin 1.5 does its thing--I can view my app using `http://localhost:8080...`
just fine, but I want to know where the actual .ear is being put.

It is not in my `jboss7.../standalone/deployments` folder.   So where is it?  My app is obviously running in jboss 7.1 just fine, but I can't find the .ear file.  I know that there is an .ear in Eclipse's 'target' directory, but that wasn't produced by jboss-as-maven-plugin is it?  I hope you can understand my confusion--don't all .ear files need to be in the deployments directory?  I also do see my .ear file inside my hidden .m2/repository directory, but does this have any interaction with jboss-as-maven-plugin?  Maybe there is some hidden sym-linking between my Eclipse project's 'target' directory and the jboss7.1 standalone/deployment directory?

p.s. I am used to using a hard-deploy option with the other plugin jboss-maven that requires you to say `jboss:hard-deploy` which just copies the .ear to your deployments folder.  Then jboss would pick up the new .ear and redeploy automatically.  I get the sense that jboss-as-maven-plugin is the preferred plugin so that's why I am bothering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jboss-as-maven-plugin uses the deployment API so it doesn't copy the file to the deployments directory for the scanner to pick it up. It deploys just as if you deployed it from the web console or via CLI. The files should be located somewhere in the `$JBOSS_HOME/standalone/data/` directory.

You're welcome to [open an issue](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBASMP), for a discussion around it at least. I'm not sure how I feel about adding a goal for it, but here isn't the place to discuss that :)

Comment: Hi James, thank you for this knowledge.  But if I wish to automatically copy an .ear or .war to the deployments directory, are there plugins that do this?  I could not get the jboss-maven plugin's hard-deploy command to work with jboss 7.  I just like the idea of having the .ear in the right folder where it should be.  Keep things uniform instead of too much magic.

Comment: That's not necessarily the "right" folder though. If you deploy an application through the web console or CLI it does not go into that folder. That folder is for the deployment scanner by default.